# Confused about stunnel's TIMEOUTclose setting

Tags: stunnel

I understand from the [stunnel documentation](http://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html) and from what I read on the Internet that MS has a buggy implementation of SSL; it fails to send a close_notify thing. The solution, says the documentation, is to set TIMEOUTclose=0. Being far from an SSL expert, I don't understand the implications of this setting. Won't it result in discarding close_notify from all browsers? Won't this create a security issue?

In addition, the [stunnel faq](http://www.stunnel.org/?page=faq) says:

> Currently stunnel implements ugly 10-seconds timeout to work with Microsoft...

How is this related to TIMEOUTclose? Is 10 the default value of TIMEOUTclose? What does IE do during this time?

Comment: It *is* an unclean shutdown, which is generally not desirable, supposedly. I don't think that it implies an immediate security concern.